# Django - Session expiration renewal

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, session, django-sessions

I'm struggling with a question about sessions.

I wonder how to make a session expire if the user has not tried to connect to the website in a certain period of time (15 days for example).
In other words, I would like to renew the expiration date of a user session each time he/she is connecting to the site.

I scrapped a lot of websites but I couldn't find any valuable example.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? You might want to take a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions

Comment: You can use the `request.session.set_expiry()` function to set an new expiry date for the session every time a view is called.

Comment: So this function modifies the SESSION_COOKIE_AGE or it sets another parameter? I don't get the difference between the call of set_expiry() and just change the parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your settings.py set `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 15 * 60 # 15 Minutes
```

Know more in the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE

Comment: Thanks for replying. But in my understanding, if a user is connecting to the site at 3:00 pm, the session will expire at 3:15 pm, no matter if there's been a connection within this time lapse. What I want is if there is a connection at 3:10 pm, so the expiry is set to 3:25 pm.

Comment: if someone ever stumbles on this, the above is not true. Django does not send a new session cookie with each request, hence the session will timeout at 3.15pm and the user has to log in. One can set SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST but this has performance impacts as the session is written to the database on each request

Comment: @SebastianSchuon, okay as a work around for `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` being resource heavy, creating middleware that alters `request.session.set_expiry()` to be whatever timeframe is needed based on last usage is a simple solution

Answer (score 3):

If you set **"True"** to [**SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) on **"settings.py"** as shown below, automatically, **session** is renewed(updated) every time the current page is reopened or other page is opened in **Django Project**.

```py
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True # False by default
```

For example, **session** expires in **15 minutes**. Then, from **3:00 pm**, **a session** starts by logging in the page in **Django Project** so **the session** expires at **3:15 pm**. Then, at **3:10 pm**, the current page is reopened or other page is opened in **Django Project** so **the session** is renewed(updated) so **the new session** expires at **3:25 pm** which means you are logged in until **3:25 pm**.

Answer (score 1):

One good solution, that I currently implement in one of my systems, if you would like your session to automatically renew on each request would be to write middleware that alters the expiration of the session to be extended in whichever views you need.

**Note: this solution does make 2 DB queries for each request. 1 for the read and 1 for the update. This is a very small overhead (using debug toolbar at most the calls are usually only a few MS), but it is there.**

For example:

```
from functools import wraps
from [project] import settings

class CookieMiddleware(object):
    """
    This middleware sets the login cookie to update timeout on every request
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    @staticmethod
    def process_view(request, view_func, args, kwargs):
        # ensure that we don't want to exclude this from running
        if getattr(view_func, 'cookie_not_important', False):
            print('cookie not important:', view_func.__name__)
            return None

        # the cookie is set, let's now set a new expire time to 30 minutes from now
        print('cookie expiry changed:', view_func.__name__)
        # it is probably smartest to grab this value back from settings
        expire_time = settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE
        # expire_time = 30 * 60
        request.session.set_expiry(expire_time)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response


def cookie_not_important(view_func):
    """
    Decorator used to allow the exclusion of the cookie time being reset
    :param view_func: The view being wrapped
    :return:
    """

    def view_being_wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

    view_being_wrapped.cookie_not_important = True
    return wraps(view_func)(view_being_wrapped)
```

And now you can login and hit any view not wrapped by `@cookie_not_important` and the expiration time will reset based on the current value in settings.py

This is how the view would look wrapped though for completeness:

```
from django.urls import reverse

@cookie_not_important
def logout(request):
    del request.session
    return redirect(reverse('some_view_name'))
```